# Разбиение на подстроки lua

Tags: регулярные-выражения, lua

Есть строка:

```
Медь, Золото (13, 13), Алмазы (32), Серебро
```

Всё, что я придумал для её разбора:

```
for medal in string.gmatch(medalsStr, '([А-яёЁ0-9с-я%.%-— \(\)]+,),?%s?') do
    table.insert(result, medal)
end
```

Но тогда разбивается по запятым:

```
Медь
Золото (13
13)
Алмазы (32)
Серебро
```

А надо:

```
Медь
Золото (13, 13)
Алмазы (32)
Серебро
```

Выражаясь на JavaScript, мне нужно получить

```
.match(/([А-я1-9 ()]*?(\(.*\))?), /g)
```

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local str = 'Медь, Золото (13, 13), Алмазы (32), Серебро'

for a in (str..'()')
    :gsub('(.-)(%b())', function(t,p) return t:gsub('%s*,%s*','\0')..p end)
    :sub(1,-3)
    :gmatch'%Z+' 
do
  print(a)
end
```

Демонстрация работы кода на IDEone:
http://ideone.com/FXEpXI